# how to decrypt the hex string created by sha2 function

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql, sha2

Is there a way to decrypt the hex string created by sha2 function.

Basically we created a hex string based on two columns of a dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only something which is encrypted can be decrypted. SHA-2 is not an encryption algorithm, it is a **S**ecure **H**ash **A**lgorithm.